# Detect the word after a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long text and part of the text is

> Hello , i am John how (1)are (are/is) you?

I used this to detect `(1)`.

```
string optionPattern = "[\\(]+[0-9]+[\\)]";
Regex reg = new Regex(optionPattern);
```

But I got stuck here at continue on how to detect after `(1)` to find `are`.

Full code ( thanks to [falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) for bringing me this far) :

```
string optionPattern = @"(?<=\(\d+\))\w+";
Regex reg = new Regex(optionPattern);

string[] passage = reg.Split(lstQuestion.QuestionContent);
foreach (string s in passage)
{
    TextBlock tblock = new TextBlock();
    tblock.FontSize = 19;
    tblock.Text = s;
    tblock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow;
    wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tblock);
}
```

I assume if I split like this, it will remove all the words after (0-9), however when I run it it only removes the word after `()` in the last detection.

[image]

As you can see the word after (7) is gone but the rest is not.

How do I detect the `are` after the `(1)`?
Is it possible to replace the word after (1) with a textbox too?

Comment: +1 for an actual regex question with effort. I take it theres more to it thats stopping you using `string.Split("(1)")`?

Comment: Yeah i have actually done reg.Spilt(the long text) but my real aim is to get the word after (1) , by doing spilt , i am removing all the (0-9) in the text

Comment: _replace the word after (1) with a textbox too_, what do you mean by that? Also, the question's tags are a little bit confusing...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind lookup (`(?<=\(\d+\))\w+`):

```
string text = "Hello , i am John how (1)are (are/is) you?";
string optionPattern = @"(?<=\(\d+\))\w+";
Regex reg = new Regex(optionPattern);
Console.WriteLine(reg.Match(text));
```

prints `are`

Alternative: capture a group `(\w+)`

```
string text = "Hello , i am John how (1)are (are/is) you?";
string optionPattern = @"\(\d+\)(\w+)";
Regex reg = new Regex(optionPattern);
Console.WriteLine(reg.Match(text).Groups[1]);
```

BTW, using `@".."`, you don't need to escape `\`.

---

**UPDATE**

Instead of using `.Split()`, just `.Replace()`:

```
string text = "Hello , i am John how (1)are (are/is) you?";
string optionPattern = @"(?<=\(\d+\))\s*\w+";
Regex reg = new Regex(optionPattern);
Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(text, ""));
```

alternative:

```
string text = "Hello , i am John how (1)are (are/is) you?";
string optionPattern = @"(\(\d+\))\s*\w+";
Regex reg = new Regex(optionPattern);
Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(text, @"$1"));
```

prints

```
Hello , i am John how (1) (are/is) you?
```

Comment: @user2376998, Do you want the result `Hello , i am John how (1) (are/is) you?`?

Comment: yeah thats what i meant , the first step for me is to make the word disappear and then 2nd step is to replace it with a textbox

Comment: @user2376998, I added a code. See **UPDATE** part in my answer.

Comment: So if i have a very long text with many (1) , (2) .... i used replace(text , "") , it will find all the pattern and replace with blank?

Comment: @user2376998, Yes, it returns the replaced string.

Comment: hmm i tried your updated codes , it still gives me the same problem where only the last pattern it remove and replace with blank , the rest is still there ? check my update for screenshot

Comment: @user2376998, I can't see the screenshot. Could you provide the sample text.

Comment: Its loading , sorry pls check again

Comment: @user2376998, Your text contians space between paren-number and word. I updated the code (UPDATE part only for now). Check it out.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot , sorry to trouble u further , but do u know how to write a regex pattern to find the word between (1) - (are/is) because i notice some of them consist of 2 words so it would be good to detect after (1) and before (

Comment: @user2376998, `@"(?<=\(\d+\)).*?(?=\()"`

Comment: @user2376998, If you don't want surround spaces, use `@"(?<=\(\d+\)\s*)\w+(?=\s*\()"` instead.

Comment: @falsetru I suggest to use `(?<=\(\d+\))\S+` instead of `(?<=\(\d+\))\w+`.

Comment: it work for (1) so much (whole/ so much) ? it can replace so much with blank?

Comment: @user2376998, `@"(?<=\(\d+\)).*?(?=\()"` will.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
\((?<number>[0-9]+)\)(?<word>\w+)
```

Groups already added for ease of use. :)

Comment: Never ever match word characters with `[a-zA-Z]` - this will fail all foreign languages using anything but plain characters, or even "borrowed" terms such as "à discretion".

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string text = "Hello , i am John how (1)are (are/is) you?";
string optionPattern = "[\\(]+[0-9]+[\\)]";
Regex reg = new Regex(optionPattern);
Match t = reg.Match(text);
int totallength = t.Index + t.Length;
string final = text.Substring(totallength,text.length-totallength);
```

in string final remaining text after (1) will store.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the text (I'm assuming that you are looking for some HTML), try:

```
var input = "Hello , i am John how (1)are (are/is) you?";
var output= Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\(\d*\))\w*", m => {
    return "<input type='text'/>";
});
```

And this is how the output is being rendered: http://jsfiddle.net/dUHeJ/.